# Get latitude and longitude of nearest seaside

Tags: python, data, google-maps-api

I have latitude and longitude of a point and I want to find out lat&long of (or distance to) a nearest seaside point.

Which way to do this will you recommend?

GIS technologies are new to me.

Comment: Are you using any specific GIS software: ArcGIS, QGIS, MapInfo, etc.? Or do you want a pure python solution?

Comment: I use only google maps API to get lat&long of place. And I totally green in GIS software and technicues you use to get data. Python solution is prefferable if exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest (not sure what region you are in) do a web search for "coastal shapefile" and download it, then use shapely python module to find the nearest polyline feature/coordinate to your point lng/lat coordinate, see this q/a:

[Coordinate of the closest point on a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415806/coordinate-of-the-closest-point-on-a-line)

Comment: I am Worldwide =) "coastal shapefile" very promising sentence. I did web search before ask, but didn't knew how to name this thing =)